# What's the relationship between these two isomorphisms involving G and T?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with maximal torus $T$ and Weyl group $W$. Recall the following two isomorphisms.

**Isomorphism 1:** $R(G) \cong R(T)^W$, where $R(-)$ denotes the representation ring.

**Isomorphism 2:** $H^{\bullet}(BG, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H^{\bullet}(BT, \mathbb{Q})^W$.

> What relationship is there, if any, between these two isomorphisms? Can I see them both as special cases of some more fundamental fact?

It's tempting to conjecture a relationship involving K-theory but I don't know how to make this work out. In particular, any finite-dimensional representation $V$ of $G$ determines a vector bundle on $BG$ and hence a class in $K^{\bullet}(BG)$, and I hoped that I could apply the Chern character to this class, but for a space like $BG$ with infinite cohomological dimension the Chern character lands in the direct product, rather than the direct sum, of the cohomology groups. There is some story here involving equivariant K-theory and the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem but I am not sure it is enough to, say, deduce either of Isomorphism 1 or 2 from the other.

Here is another even vaguer attempt. By Peter-Weyl, some version of Isomorphism 1 should follow from a suitable isomorphism of the form $G/G \cong T/W$, where on the LHS I am taking the quotient with respect to conjugation. (I'm not sure exactly what category these quotients should be happening in.) On the other hand, Isomorphism 2 should follow from something like the observation that the fiber sequence $G/T \to BT \to BG$ gives a fiber sequence $(G/T)/W \to (BT)/W \to BG$, where $(G/T)/W$ has the rational homotopy type of a point, at least if I'm reading Allen Knutson's answer correctly [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/61991/290), and by the quotient $(BT)/W$ I mean the homotopy quotient. So $(BT)/W \to BG$ is a rational homotopy equivalence, and I might be able to go from this map $(BT)/W \to BG$ to a map $T/W \to G/G$ by taking some version of the free loop space. Maybe? (I might need to work with stacks instead of spaces.)

**Edit:** I think the two isomorphisms above can be restated in terms of equivariant K-theory and equivariant cohomology respectively as follows:

**Isomorphism 1.1:** $K_G^{\bullet}(\text{pt}) \cong K_T^{\bullet}(\text{pt})^W$

**Isomorphism 2.1:** $H_G^{\bullet}(\text{pt}, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_T^{\bullet}(\text{pt}, \mathbb{Q})^W$

One way to probe the relationship between these two isomorphisms further, then, is to ask:

> What happens when I replace $\text{pt}$ above with some other $G$-space? In what generality do the two isomorphisms above continue to hold? What other equivariant cohomology theories can I use here?

In particular, if we find that after replacing $\text{pt}$ by more general spaces one of the isomorphisms holds for different spaces than the other, that would be evidence against a more fundamental fact having them both as corollaries.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but let me try to clarify one thing that I probably said hastily in a talk some time. Of course, there is no equivalence (or even a map) of stacks $T/W \to G/G$ - the stabilizers are all wrong, even if the orbit spaces agree. Let us write $N=N_G(T)$. You do have a map of stacks $BN \to BG$, which gives a map on loop spaces $N/N \to G/G$ ($BN$ is what you write as $BT/W$). Inside $N/N$ you have a copy of $T/N = (T/T)/W$ which also maps to $G/G$. Not sure what else to say yet.

Comment: Isn't $G/N$ rationally contractible ($N$ the normalizer of a maximal torus)? That would imply a rational equivalence $BN\to BG$ and that any rational cohomology theory can be computed on $BN$.

Comment: In addition to $H_G^*(X, {\Bbb Q}) = H_T^*(X, {\Bbb Q})^W$ (any space $X$, essentially due to Borel), these isomorphisms also hold for equivariant Chow groups and (higher) algebraic $K$-theory (of coherent sheaves).  I think it's also true for (algebraic/topological) cobordism, but don't know much about that subject.  The unifying theme is a version of the splitting principle; the proofs I know in these different contexts use different techniques, though it's certainly reasonable to ask for a mother-of-all proof.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt I'm not sure what "rationally contractible" means, but Allen Knutson's answer, linked by Qiaochu above, shows that $G/N(T)$ has the rational cohomology of a point, and I know that $\pi_1(T) \to \pi_1(G)$ is surjective, so that should show $\pi_1(G/T)$ is trivial and hence $\pi_1(G/N(T))$ is $W$. Is $\pi_1$ finite and $H^{\ast}(\ , \mathbb{Q})=0$ the same as rationally contractible? (Notation note: $N$ usually the unipotent part of a Borel in this context, so I'm writing $N(T)$.)

Comment: @David: presumably it means having the rational homotopy type of a point. I think that is implied by $\pi_1$ finite and rational cohomology vanishing by Whitehead-Serre.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, also: $G/T$ is homotopic to $G/B$ and is therefore simply connected...

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: yes, for finite CW-complexes. It means that in rational homotopy, $G/N$ is equivalent to the point and thus all rational cohomology theories like singular cohomology, K-theory, cobordism (all with rational coefficients) are trivial for $G/N$. I thought a bit more about this, and the rational contractibility of $G/N$ also implies that $X\times^N EG\to X\times^GEG$ also induces isomorphisms in all rational cohomology theories for $X$ any finite $G$-CW-complex. I think this explains the equivariant rational isomorphisms in the question.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt, I understand this argument for Borel-equivariant cohomology theories, but what about equivariant $K$-theory?  One can use the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem to deduce isomorphisms $\hat{K_G(X)} = \hat{K_T(X)}^W$ but it's still not quite clear to me that you can undo the completion.

Comment: @DaveAnderson: I am not sure if we need Atiyah-Segal to deduce the relation between $K_G(X)$ and the Weyl invariants, the Atiyah-Segal theorem compares the K-theory to the (completion of the) representation ring. I think to compare the two different equivariant K-theories, we may not need it?

Comment: @Matthias: I think Dave's point is that your argument works for Borel-equivariant K-theory but it's not clear that one can go from this to the same statement for what is usually called equivariant K-theory. Atiyah-Segal compares the former to the completion of the latter, but as Dave says it's unclear whether this completion can be undone.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan,@DaveAnderson: ok, I misunderstood, sorry. You are right, this argument works for things defined by the Borel construction.

Comment: Note that the functor $K_T^\bullet(-)$ is a cohomology theory for $G$-spaces. It is not clear that the functor $K_T^\bullet(-)^W$ satisfies the exactness axiom if you do not do something like invert the order of $W$. (In fact I think I have a counterexample.)

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: Do you happen to remember this counterexample? It would be useful to have on record.

Answer (score 7):

Some googling has led me to an answer to the second question, at least: $H_G^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_T^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{Q})^W$ holds for any $G$-space $X$ and the argument is essentially the same, and I learned from a [paper of Harada, Landweber, and Sjamaar](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1629) that $K_G^{\bullet}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong (K_T^{\bullet}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q})^W$ holds at least for $X$ compact (actually we only need to invert $|W|$). So this is encouraging, although I don't know how similar the proofs can be made.