# The mod p cohomologies of classifying spaces of compact Lie groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology, classifying-spaces

I want to do some computation which need the mod p cohomologies of classifying spaces of connected compact Lie groups as input. I need the table for both the simply connected case and the central quotient case($G/\Gamma$, $\Gamma\subset Z(G)$). Are there a complete table for all these results.

Comment: Not for homology, but for homotopy groups, I always end up at the tables of the deputy director of the SCGP: http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/~abanov/Teaching/Spring2009/Notes/abanov-cpA1-upload.pdf

Comment: If $p$ is coprime to $\lvert W\rvert$, where $W$ is the Weyl group, then you can compute $H^*(BG; \mathbb F_p)$ in terms of a maximal torus, as described in [this MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61784/cohomology-of-bg-g-compact-lie-group).

Answer (score 3):

In the book of Mimura-Toda "Topology of Lie groups" you can find a lot of the computations you are interested on.

Comment: Thank you! Arun Debray. The book really contains some examples like $BG_2$ for $Z_2$ and $BF_4$ for $Z_2$. But I want more: for example $BE_8$ for $p=2,3,5$.  Are there a complete table for all these results?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, H<sup>*</sup>(BG,<sub>p</sub>) is a polynomial algebra, generated in the degrees of the Weyl group.

The exceptional cases are known as torsion primes. If G is simply connected and simple, there are no such primes in type A or C, they are 2 in types B (except B<sub>2</sub>), D and G, 2 and 3 in types E<sub>6</sub> and E<sub>7</sub>, and 2, 3 and 5 in E<sub>8</sub>. A precise definition is in Definition 2.43 of "Parity Sheaves", by Juteau, Mautner and Williamson.

To get an idea of the cohomology in one of the unusual cases, there is
$$H^*(BSO_3;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[b,w] $$
where the generators b and w are in degrees 2 and 3. This is not actually hard to prove via a spectral sequence once you have the guts to believe that the cohomology ring is this big.

For a general reference for computing this cohomology ring, look at "Torsion in cohomology of compact Lie groups and Chow rings of reductive algebraic groups" by Kac.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Are there a table for all these results as complete as possible. For example it contains the result for $BE_8$ with $p=2,3,5$.